# Divide a matrix by a vector

Tags: matlab

**Question:** I'm trying to divide a `3x63` matrix (every row of it) by a `1x63` vector (which is the last row of the matrix) and matlab shouts at me that 
`Matrix dimensions must agree.` 
What am I doing wrong here?

```
coords_ = load('m1.mat')
x2D = coords_ .x2D
[rows, columns] = size(x2D)
last_row_2d = x2D(end ,:)
mat_2d = repmat (x2D ,[rows columns])
new_mat = mat_2d ./ last_row_2d
```

Comment: Your solution you posted as an answer is better (i.e. use broadcasting), but just to point out the error with your initial approach `mat_2d = repmat (x2D ,[rows columns])` here you don't want to repeat the columns, only the rows. Otherwise the dimensions of `mat_2d` would be 3 rows by 63*63 columns

Comment: @Dan Yeah I used the debugger and saw its dimensions and understood that this function won't help me. Thank you Dan.

Comment: It could have worked, just not efficiently. You needed to do it like this: `repmat (x2D ,[rows 1])` to repeat only the rows. But broadcasting is more efficient than using `repmat` for this.

Comment: Oh I see. yeah I always use broadcasting in python w/ arrays so that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just did that and it worked:

```
last_row_2d = x2D(end ,:)
new_mat = x2D(1:2,:) ./ last_row_2d
```